# MIDI is not defined

Tags: angular, web-midi

After upgrading the `8.1.3` release of `angular` to `~9.0.6` and a few other dependencies I get the following error:

```
loader.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: MIDI is not defined
    at Object.../../node_modules/midi/js/loader.js (loader.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.../../node_modules/abcjs/src/midi/abc_midi_controls.js (abc_midi_controls.js:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.../../node_modules/abcjs/src/api/abc_tunebook_midi.js (abc_tunebook_midi.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.../../node_modules/abcjs/midi.js (midi.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module.../midi-lib/src/lib/service/sheet.service.ts (sheet.service.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

The source code of the dependency having the error:

```
if (typeof MIDI === 'undefined') MIDI = {};
```

I tried downgrading:
`abcjs` from `^5.12.0` back to `^5.6.11`
`@types/webmidi` from `^2.0.4` back to `^2.0.3`
`web-midi-api` from `^2.0.7` back to `^2.0.5`
`typescript` from `^3.7.5` back to `^3.4.5`
but it did not change anything.

UPDATE:
When removing the `abcjs` dependency from the `package.json` file, the error was gone and the project application behaved all right.

Here is the upgraded dependencies list from the now working application. Note how the `abcjs` dependency is gone.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tonejs/midi": "^2.0.15",
    "@types/webmidi": "^2.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "fstream": "^1.0.12",
    "midi-file-slicer": "^5.0.45",
    "midi-json-parser": "^6.4.19",
    "nexusui": "^2.0.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tone": "^13.4.9",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "vexflow": "^1.2.90",
    "web-midi-api": "^2.0.7",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.6",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.900.6",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  }
```

Comment: have you try include this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/midi)

Comment: I just did. I now installed the midi dependency release `^1.0.0` but it did not change anything to the error.

Comment: so its dev dependency so try one time that package as per i suggest.

Comment: Removing the `abcjs ^5.12.0` dependency removed the issue. I guess there is something wrong in this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following?

```
  "abcjs": "6.0.0-beta.8",
```

I will look at this as soon as I can, but I think that version doesn't depend on the midi.js library by default.

[EDIT]
Also, how are you including abcjs? Something like:

```
const abcjs = require("abcjs");
```

or some other way?

Comment: Here is how I define the global `import abcjs from 'abcjs/midi';     const sheetAbc = abcjs.renderAbc(name, strNotes, {
      add_classes: true
     });
` 
Now I did upgrade the dependency as seen in the `package.json` file content: `"abcjs": "^6.0.0-beta.8",` but after re-serving the application, the browser console showed the exact same error.